# Error on build.gradle In Visual Studio Code(Flutter)

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying to build an app for the Google Play Store and need to make a signed and released APK. I tried updating both build.gradle files, but I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/herb/Downloads/morningly/android/app/build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_4k00465lacv9h9hnlvfrbb5oa$_run_closure2@7532b849] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Here are my build.gradle files:

`android build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    } 
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
} 

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/app build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.morningly"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now, I followed this article (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) to help me with this process. I made sure that I edited the right Gradle files, and I even checked over answers, but no avail. Please, if you have any input, let me know. I desperately want to upload my app.

Comment: Your missing the **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'** just above line 30 of your **android/app build.gradle** file. It does not understand *android{}* without this. Move **apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'** up too.

Comment: @Jon Goodwin Thank you, this fixed the android{} problem, but now there is a problem with flutter() `Could not find method flutter() for arguments [build_4k00465lacv9h9hnlvfrbb5oa$_run_closure3@2347bae0] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing the:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

just above `line 30` of your `android/app` `build.gradle` file. It does not understand `android{}` without this. **Move**:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

*up* too, too keep it **tidy** and *best to read it early*, later stuff may **depend** on it.

Answer (score 0):

throw  new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

I have the error that I open  android/apps/build.gradle/ errroe just pop in
to solve it I just remove "new"from the Gradel Expection.
throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).